# Find efficient way of migration 2TB GBK table in SybaseIQ to UTF-8 files

Tags: migration, sybase, utf-8, sybaseiq

My project need to migrate more than 2TB raw data from SybaseIQ to another Database. SybaseIQ using GBK, the target Database using UTF-8, the target database can only load from UTF-8 files.

We use [The Extract Options](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1540/doc/html/san1288042629439.html) to extract data to GBK files first, then convert data into UTF-8, the converting is very slow because it's single processor only.

Can anyone tell me the efficient way of extract data from SybaseIQ and convert charset and encode to UTF-8?

Comment: Which is the target database?

Answer (score 0):

I've promoted about 2X speed by named pipe.

First step:(create a named pipe)

```
mkfifo p1
```

Second step:(waiting to convert)

```
cat p1| iconv -f GBK -t UTF-8 > target.file
```

Last step:(export to p1, see the sql scripts below)

```
SET OPTION TEMP_EXTRACT_NAME1 = 'p1';
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;
SET OPTION TEMP_EXTRACT_NAME1 = '';
```